# Using multiple sessions

Tags: php, session

I have two scripts which will be executed by two separate URL requests and which will have independent sessions.  Script1 will set a session, and script2 needs to display script1's session.

Originally, I created `getOtherSessionR1()`, and obtained the desired functionality, however, the script seemed to run out of sequence.  I say this since I added multiple `syslog()`, and they did not write to the log in the order I expected.  I believe this was caused by the various headers created by `session_start()`.  Am I correct in my belief?

I then created `getOtherSessionR2()`, and it seems to work perfect.  Is there any problems with using this method, and/or is there a better way to use multiple sessions?

script1.php

```
<?php
session_name('SESSION1');
session_start();
$_SESSION['key']='hello';
//bla bla bla
?>
```

script2.php

```
<?php
session_name('SESSION2');
session_start();
$_SESSION['key']='goodby';
//bla bla bla
$session1=library::getOtherSession('SESSION1');
echo($session1['key']);   //hello
//bla bla bla
?>
```

methods in library class

```
public static function getOtherSessionR1($name)
{
    if(isset($_COOKIE[$name]) && is_string($_COOKIE[$name])) {
        $session_id_current = session_id($_COOKIE[$name]);
        session_write_close();
        session_start();
        $session_other=$_SESSION;
        session_id($session_id_current);
        session_write_close();
        session_start();
    }
    else {$session_other=false;}
    return $session_other;
}


public static function getOtherSessionR2($name)
{
    if(isset($_COOKIE[$name]) && is_string($_COOKIE[$name]) && $session_other_file=file_get_contents(session_save_path().'/sess_'.$_COOKIE[$name])) {
        $session_current=$_SESSION;
        session_decode($session_other_file);
        $session_other=$_SESSION;
        $_SESSION=$session_current;
    }
    else {$session_other=false;}
    return $session_other;
}
```

Comment: i'm curious why u want to use 2 sessions. Can't use just something like `$_SESSION['page1'] = [];` and `$_SESSION['page2']`

Comment: @DarkBee  I could in deed do so, however, doing so will complicate other portions of the script.  If I can't find a safe way to using two sessions, I will resort to doing so.